# Compare data in array and count the number of instances it occurs in the database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this array month `$monthsNum = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];`, and I want this to be compared in my database column **month_uploaded** with values just ranging from 1-12. I want it to count the number of instances the **$monthsNum** array values occurs in column **month_uploaded** and stored it in array **$count_uploads**.Zero count is placed with zero value in array $count_uploads. How would I do that? Your help is much appreciated. Thank you. Below are pieces of my codes.

[image]

```
function count_uploads_perMonth(){

  $monthsNum = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];

  $query = $this->db->select("*")
                    ->from($this->table_par)
                    ->where_in("month_uploaded",$monthsNum)
                    ->get();


      foreach( $query->result() as $row ){

        $count_uploads[] = count($row->month_uploaded);

      }

      var_dump($count_uploads);

}
```

Output: Wrong

```
array (size=5)
0 => int 1
1 => int 1
2 => int 1
3 => int 1
4 => int 1
```

Desired Output:

```
 array (size=12)
 0 => 0 or null
 1 => 0 or null
 2 => 0 or null
 3 => 0 or null
 4 => 0 or null
 5 => 1
 6 => 3 
 7 => 0 or null
 8 => 0 or null
 9 => 0 or null
10 => 0 or null
11 => 0 or null
```

This is closer, just have to get the right count value for each array key

```
function count_uploads_perMonth(){

  $monthsNum = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12');
  $this->db->select("month_uploaded as cnt");
  $this->db->where_in('month_uploaded',$monthsNum);
  $this->db->group_by('month_uploaded');
  $query = $this->db->get($this->table_par);

  $count_uploads = array_fill(1, 12, 0);

    foreach( $query->result() as $row ){

      $count_uploads[$row->cnt] = $row->cnt;

    }
    var_dump($count_uploads);

}
```

Output:

```
 array (size=12)
 1 => int 0
 2 => int 0
 3 => int 0
 4 => int 0
 5 => int 0
 6 => string '6' (length=1)  --- value should be 1 and length is 1
 7 => string '7' (length=1)  --- value should be 4 and length is 4
 8 => int 0
 9 => int 0
 10 => int 0
 11 => int 0
 12 => int 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think what you need over here is `array_count_values`. You just make an array of result from your query using `->get()->result_array();`

```
$array = range(1,12);
$result = array(7,7,7,6);
$final = array_count_values($result);
$final_array = array();
foreach($array as $value){
    $final_array[$value] = array_key_exists($value ,$final) ? $final[$value] : 0;
}
print_r($final_array);
```

**Edited :**

As per your resulted array you can update your array as

```
$arr = array(0 => array ('month_uploaded' =>  '7'),  1 => array ('month_uploaded' =>  '7'),  2 => array ('month_uploaded' =>  '7'), 3 => array ('month_uploaded' =>  '7'),  4 => array ('month_uploaded' =>  '6' ));
$result = array_count_values(array_column($arr,'month_uploaded'));
$final_array = array();
foreach($array as $value){
    $final_array[$value] = array_key_exists($value ,$result) ? $result[$value] : 0;
}
print_r($final_array);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/401385)

Comment: how could i replace the value in $result = array(7,7,7,6); to make it more dynamic?

Comment: Can you post the value of `$query` what you were getting within it

Comment: You were showing the result of single column not an array of result just replace `->get()` into `->get()->result_array();` and post the value of `print_r($query);`

Comment: array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month_uploaded' => string '7' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month_uploaded' => string '7' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month_uploaded' => string '7' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month_uploaded' => string '7' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'month_uploaded' => string '6' (length=1)

Comment: how could i replace the value in $result = array(7,7,7,6) with the values found in my database to make it more dynamic?

Comment: @Eli You're Welcome. Glad to help (_FYI: You can upvote those answer that really helps you_)

Answer (score 1):

Append the count to array with months as keys.

```
$count_uploads[$row->month_uploaded][] = $row->month_uploaded;
```

Now, you will get array with month as key and appended values as values.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($count_uploads);
echo '</pre>';
```

Sample array

```
array(
  3 => array(3, 3),
  4 = array()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use following functions and get your result.

function count_uploads_perMonth(){

$monthsNum = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12');
$this->db->select("count(month_uploaded) as cnt");
$this->db->where_in('month_uploaded',$monthsNum);
$this->db->group_by('month_uploaded');
$query = $this->db->get('$this->table_par');


  foreach( $query->result() as $row ){

    $count_uploads[] = $row->cnt;

  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($count_uploads);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change SQL query to

```
SELECT month_uploaded-1 `month`, COUNT(*) `count` FROM table_name GROUP BY month_uploaded
```

you will receive (5,1), (6,4). Then

```
// Prepare array with zeros
$count_uploads = array_fill(0, 12, 0);

foreach( $query->result() as $row )
   $count_uploads[$row->month] = $row->count;
```